# Any way to do this query faster with big data

Tags: mysql, mariadb

This query takes around 2.23seconds and feels a bit slow ... is there anyway to make it faster.
our member.id, member_id, membership_id, valid_to, valid_from has index as well.

```
select * 
from member 
where (member.id in ( select member_id from member_membership mm 
INNER JOIN membership m ON mm.membership_id = m.id 
where instr(organization_chain, 2513) and m.valid_to > NOW() and m.valid_from < NOW() ) ) 
order by id desc 
limit 10 offset 0
```

EXPLAIN FOR WHAT QUERY DOING: every member has many a member_memberships and and member_memberships connect with another table called membership there we have the membership details. so query will get all members that has valid memberships and where the organization id 2513 exist on member_membership.
Tables as following:

```
CREATE TABLE `member` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `member_membership` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `membership_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `member_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `organization_chain` text DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `member_membership_to_membership` (`membership_id`),
  KEY `member_membership_to_member` (`member_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `membership` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valid_to` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `valid_from` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `valid_to` (`valid_to`),
  KEY `valid_from` (`valid_from`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `member_membership` ADD CONSTRAINT `member_membership_to_membership` FOREIGN KEY (`membership_id`) REFERENCES `membership` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `member_membership` ADD CONSTRAINT `member_membership_to_member` FOREIGN KEY (`member_id`) REFERENCES `member` (`id`);
```

Here with EXPLAIN statement =>  https://i.ibb.co/xjrcYWR/EXPLAIN.png

Relations

- member has many member_membership
- membership has manymember_membership
- So member_membership is like join for tables member and membership.

Comment: all optimize questions need a EXPLAIN your query and you must show tables and where their indexes are

Comment: I added EXPLAIN and tables too!

Comment: this is not good, images doesn't help and i can't see which indexes you have. and a explain should result in such a table https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4yPorU6k3SjQ5nmhgi1wGo/42

Comment: The indexes is there below each table!. I dont understand what is missing!

Comment: please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and post text

Comment: @trincot , its on member_membership if u check the image u see all tables.

Comment: @nbk , Its hard to copy whole table and paste it as text.. Image much easier to see all and understand it.

Comment: We disagree. It is general policy to not post images of what is essentially text. Most helpful would be to post the SQL statements to set up tables and data. That will increase the probability of getting a useful answer considerably.

Comment: OK nice, I fixed my question.. added query for every table there!

Comment: You also have to realize that some of us are allowed to visit SO but not third party image sites.

Comment: you can try to use a combined key for membership with all 3 columns

Comment: @nbk valid_to & valid_from should not be unique so can not make it PRIMARY key

Comment: make a simple key **not** a primary key

Comment: Text, please, for the `EXPLAIN`.  The image is not available.

Answer (score 1):

Well I found a way to make it less to 800ms ... like this. Is this good way or maybe there is more we can do?

```
select * 
from member  
where (member.id in ( select member_id from member_membership mm FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY)
INNER JOIN membership m ON mm.membership_id = m.id  
where instr(organization_chain, 2513) and m.valid_to > NOW() and m.valid_from < NOW() ) ) 
order by id desc 
limit 10 offset 0
```

NEW UPDATE.. and I think this solve the issue.. 15ms :)
I added FORCE INDEX..
The FORCE INDEX hint acts like USE INDEX (index_list), with the addition that a table scan is assumed to be very expensive. In other words, a table scan is used only if there is no way to use one of the named indexes to find rows in the table.

```
 select * 
from member  
where (member.id in ( select member_id from member_membership mm FORCE INDEX (member_membership_to_member)
INNER JOIN membership m FORCE INDEX (organization_to_membership) ON mm.membership_id = m.id  
where instr(organization_chain, 2513) and m.valid_to > NOW() and m.valid_from < NOW() ) ) 
order by id desc 
limit 10 offset 0
```

Comment: If you would explain why it is faster and what you have optimized this could become a great learning resource.

Answer (score 0):

How big is `organization_chain`?  If you don't need `TEXT`, use a reasonably sized `VARCHAR` so that it could be in an index.  Better yet, is there some way to get 2513 in a column by itself?

Don't use `id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,` in a many-to-many table; rather have the two columns in `PRIMARY KEY`.

Put the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` in the subquery.

Don't use `IN ( SELECT ...)`, use a `JOIN`.

Comment: organization_chain does not affact if its text or varchar. the big issue comes now when the data get bigger more and more.. so like 1million rows takes 15ms.. but when its 2million rows its 50ms .. thats another issue.

Comment: @Mohammed - A `TEXT` column forces a temp table to be on disk instead of in RAM -- this slows down the `ORDER BY`. Pulling the 2513 out, if possible, could lead to an index that would help _significantly_.

Comment: Thank u Rick James for this info :) will check that and change it to varchar!